# Grammar: “ne me sentais pas” or “ne sentais pas”

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, verbes-pronominaux

I was wondering if it is absolutely necessary to place “me” right before “sentais” in the following sentence. If so, what might be the reason for that?

> Je ne me sentais pas le cœur de refuser.
>
> Je ne sentais pas le cœur de refuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Je ne sentais pas le coeur de refuser* : **incorrect**. cela n'a aucun sens et grammaticalement c'est une construction impossible.

**Je ne me sentais pas le coeur de refuser = Je ne sentais pas que j'avais le coeur de refuser.**

C'est une construction du type:

Sujet (je) verbe de perception (sentais) [sujet + structure à l'infinitif].

Où le sujet est *moi => me* , le verbe à l'infinitif implicite est *avoir*.

> Je voyais cette personne arriver.
>
> Je me voyais tomber.
>
> Je ne me voyais pas arrêter.
>
> **Je ne me sentais pas (avoir) le coeur de refuser.**
>
> **Je ne me voyais pas (avoir) le courage de le lui dire.**

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is necessary as the second form doesn't make sense in French.

> *Je ne me sentais pas le cœur de refuser.* → I didn't feel like refusing
>
> *Je ne sentais pas le cœur de refuser.* → I wasn't smelling/feeling the "hearth of refusing"

"*se sentir le cœur de*" is a French idiom. Removing the reflexive *se* breaks that idiom and its meaning.

Comment: Désolé, mais 1 : C'est négatif ou positif. Se sentir le coeur de refuser est correct . 2 la source de l'expression c'est "avoir le coeur". Se sentir le coeur = sentir que l'on a. On peut employer d'autre synonymes de perception: se croire le coeur, s'imaginer, ... http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/avoir-a-c-ur-de-faire-quelque-chose/

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina *se sentir le cœur* indeed also exists. Thanks, answer updated.

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres « le cœur » peut être omis ou remplacé par « le courage », « la force », « l'envie »...

Answer (score 2):

You are feeling here the difference between the transitive and the intransitive form of "feel" for sentir (and not smell).
In this context, intransitive, only the first form is correct.

```
feel vi (+ adj: experience emotion) se sentir⇒ v pron.
```

I did not feel courageous to refuse => « Je ne me sentais pas le cœur de refuser »

Different from the transitive form:

```
 feel [sth] vtr (be conscious of) (avoir conscience de) sentir⇒ vtr
```

He could feel her gaze on him => « Il sentait son regard »